# Select the folder and send image to that folder in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

The code below selects the folder that I want the image belongs. The user select the folder click on the 'Save' button and then the image is sent to the folder. And behind the the image is sent to the folder.

Is it possible? How can I manipulate the images behind?

Can you suggest me an idea/best practice to do this?

I dont know how to start to think about it.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  br(),
  
  pickerInput(
    selected = 'emotion',
    width = 'fit',
    inputId = paste0('emotion', '_', 1),
    label = 'Choose your folder',inline = TRUE,
    choices = c('folder_1','folder_2','folder_3','folder_4'),
    options = list(style = "btn-primary")
  ),
  br(),
  br(),
  
  p(paste0('folder', '_', 1,'.png')),
  tags$img(
    src = paste0('emocoes/', 'emotion', '/','folder_', 1,'.png'),
    class = paste0(1),
    style = ' 
    width: 350px; height: 350px;border-radius: 10px;
     '
  ),
  actionButton(inputId = 'save', 'Send')
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

can I achieve this with `updateTabsetPanel()`?

Comment: Is `emocoes/emotion/folder_1.png` supposed to be stored on the server or on the user's local machine? If the user's local machine, then you need to use `shiny::downloadButton` and `shiny::downloadHandler`. (BTW, not sure why you're pasting the file path like that, it may be more declarative to use `file.path("emocoes", "emotion", paste0("folder_", 1, ".png"))`, assuming that some or most of those string literals will really be variables in your code ... because if not, then simply `path <- "emocoes/emotion/folder_1.png"` is a lot more readable to me.

Comment: On the server @r2evans.  Initially this app is hosted on shinyapps.io 
The user can do this if the app is hosted on shinyapps.io ?

Comment: That should be fine. BTW, don't confuse this question by asking about tabsets ... figure out how to do the basic operations of (1) create an image, (2) save it to the user-selected server sub-folder, then (3) display that image in the shiny app. I see nothing here on how to create whatever image you're hoping to save to a sub-folder. Also, you cannot use `tags:img(.)` with a static path if the user is going to choose and you are going to create a new file, you'll need to use dynamic HTML such as with `uiOutput` (in your `ui`) and `renderUI` (in the `server` block).

Comment: @r2evans amazing. Thanks a lot. I will work on this app this weekend and I will answer. I think this can be useful for peaiple.